# Change grouping of an specific exception in sentry (django)

Tags: python, django, sentry, raven

I use raven with my django web application and i want to prevent an exception from excessive grouping as described in documentations [here](https://docs.sentry.io/learn/rollups/#customize-grouping-with-fingerprints) while preserving default behavior for other exceptions. 
More concretely I have a code snippet like this somewhere in my app:

```
raise Exception('Nothing done for catalog #' + str(catalog_id))
```

in sentry i see exceptions for different catalogs grouped together because it rolls them up based on stack-traces. As i understood from docs i should use something like:

```
client.captureException(fingerprint=['{{ default }}', str(catalog_id)])
```

but i don't know where in my code it should be used.

Comment: Why are you looking to prevent "excessive grouping"? Are you looking to be alerted to *every time* this "Nothing done for catalog" exception is hit?

Comment: yes. and i want the exception showed in sentry list to be classified by catalog_id

Comment: I'd actually suggest letting Sentry group (correctly), but then tagging each event with `catalog_id`. Then, you'll be able to see the distributions in the issue view sidebar and the tag view.

Comment: should i do this like: `client.captureException(tags={'catalog_id': str(catalog_id)})` ?

Comment: Yes, that should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`client.captureException(fingerprint=['{{ default }}', str(catalog_id)])` is used inside of an `except` clause.

```
try:
    raise Exception('Nothing done for catalog #' + str(catalog_id))
except Exception:
    client.captureException(fingerprint=['{{ default }}', str(catalog_id)])
```

#### Reference:

- [Capture an error](https://docs.sentry.io/clients/python/#capture-an-error)

Comment: I'm confused by the default behavior of capturing all exceptions... i suspect doing this result in double reports for this exception

Comment: In the `try` block, you usually do an operation that may raise an exception. If your wanted to group just the `KeyError` exception, you can capture that into it's own group and have other exceptions go into the default group